# Leaflet - set icon based on zoom WITH a timeout refresh

Tags: javascript, leaflet

- I'd like to have my icon change based on the zoom, which I have working! BUT, I also have a setTimeout which runs my function every 7 seconds.
- The problem is that every time the function is run, the icon gets set back to the bigBusIcon.
- I've tried putting both the marker and the zoomend in functions, but I've had no luck... Any help is much appreciated!

```
const mapBuses = function () {
    //other code is here

            L.geoJSON(getGeoJson(routeFilter), {
                onEachFeature: function (feature) {
                    let longitude = feature.coordinates[0];
                    let latitude = feature.coordinates[1];
                    let marker = L.marker([latitude, longitude], { icon: bigBusIcon, rotationAngle: feature.bearing })
                        .bindPopup(
                            `Bus Route: ${feature.routeNum}<br/>Speed: ${Math.round(feature.speed)} km/hr`
                        ).addTo(busLayer);

                    // set icon size based on zoom (although it resets every 7 seconds)
                    map.on('zoomend', function () {
                        var currentZoom = map.getZoom();
                        if (currentZoom >= 14) {
                            marker.setIcon(bigBusIcon);
                        }
                        else {
                            marker.setIcon(smallBusIcon);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    // refresh every 7 seconds    
    setTimeout(mapBuses, 7000);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the current zoom while you are initializing your layer:

```
const mapBuses = function () {
    //other code is here

            L.geoJSON(getGeoJson(routeFilter), {
                onEachFeature: function (feature) {
                    let longitude = feature.coordinates[0];
                    let latitude = feature.coordinates[1];
                    // get current zoom
                    let currentZoom = map.getZoom();
                    // add condition to chose icon
                    let myIcon = currentZoom > 14 ? bigBusIcon : smallBusIcon;
                    // use myIcon variable in marker creation
                    let marker = L.marker([latitude, longitude], { icon: myIcon, rotationAngle: feature.bearing })
                        .bindPopup(
                            `Bus Route: ${feature.routeNum}<br/>Speed: ${Math.round(feature.speed)} km/hr`
                        ).addTo(busLayer);

                    // set icon size based on zoom (although it resets every 7 seconds)
                    map.on('zoomend', function () {
                        var currentZoom = map.getZoom();
                        if (currentZoom >= 14) {
                            marker.setIcon(bigBusIcon);
                        }
                        else {
                            marker.setIcon(smallBusIcon);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    // refresh every 7 seconds    
    setTimeout(mapBuses, 7000);
};
```